# TFS/Sharepoint trust relationship broken

Tags: sharepoint, team-foundation-server

I have inherited a TFS server that was also hosting a sharepoint collection. I moved the server onto a new domain - let's call the old one DOMAIN and the new one NEW. All seemed to go OK - where I could find a username on DOMAIN I made TFS and sharepoint admins part of the new domain. The services (SQL, Sharepoint, TFS) now start as admins of NEW, and I had to mess around with database owners in SQL to change them too.

It was all running OK so I deleted the trust from DOMAIN to NEW and closed down the last DC on DOMAIN. (That was server 2012 and NEW is on 2016 level)

While TFS seems to work OK, Sharepoint is playing up - I can't login to the server on port 80 where the collection is, although I can login to the admin pages on a different port. When going to the collection directly I get:

> An unexpected error has occurred.

When I navigate to http://server I get

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>   Date: Fri, 21 Jul 2017 12:11:46 GMT
>   Connection: close

When I go into the admin pages and try to change for example authentication providers on the port 80 website, I click Default, then Save and get

> Sorry, something went wrong 
>   The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed. 
>    Technical Details 
>    Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 
>   Correlation ID: df73079e-d47a-a09d-3885-30c7ccf98f61

OK so I thought I would get everything back again, so I booted up the DOMAIN DC, reestablished the trust from NEW to DOMAIN both ways, but still the same thing.

There are a lot more details I can go into but if someone can point me in the right direction I would be grateful. I don't know sharepoint well, and I know TFS even less!  They are the 2013 version by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually migrate a Sharepoint server between domains. You have yo create a new Sharepoint in the new domain and then migrate the site collection over.

Comment: It's actually a TFS server with the sharepoint being part of the TFS install. Does your comment hold for TFS too?

Comment: It holds for SharePoint regardless of how or where it was installed. TFS can move domain if you follow the documentation, SharePoint can't.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to migrate the sharepoint OK. However what I couldn't do was upgrade it to SQL 2016 and Server 2016 at the same time. I provisioned a new server identical to the old one in regards to SQL and windows, but just with SP2013 not TFS. It was on the new domain.

I managed to restore the SQL OK and SP works